# Length of IV wrong but generated by host

Tags: python-3.x, encryption, aes, pycrypto

I register an upload with an application. I get this back:

```
{'enabled': 'true', 'cipher': 'aes-128-cbc', 'key': 'baa47c89079830de8cc0685374391280', 'iv': '4ba4dcfde54a05296392706f9200b1fe'}
```

Then I do:

```
UPLOAD_ENCRYPTION = UPLOAD["encryption"]
print(UPLOAD_ENCRYPTION)
UPLOAD_KEY = UPLOAD_ENCRYPTION["key"]
UPLOAD_CIPHER = UPLOAD_ENCRYPTION["cipher"]
UPLOAD_IV = UPLOAD_ENCRYPTION["iv"]
ENCRYPT = AES.new(UPLOAD_KEY, AES.MODE_CBC, UPLOAD_IV)
```

...and I get:

```
    self._cipher = factory.new(key, *args, **kwargs)
ValueError: IV must be 16 bytes long
```

Is the place I'm trying to upload to giving me bad info out or am I missing something?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Hex-encoded strings need to be decoded to bytes objects. Easiest method is probably calling [`bytes.fromhex()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.fromhex)

Comment: Also goes for the key, otherwise you get AES-256 with the wrong key: invalid ciphertext but no error before decryption.